# How to set just the day number inside date field SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Can I set just the day number inside a date field in SQL Server 2014? I mean just the '01' part of '2011-02-01' or do I have to convert the day field to int?

Something like:

```
UPDATE Calendar SET dayField = DAY(dates)
```

Where dates is a column of subsequent dates and dayField is type: date.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question more understandable.

Comment: I'm not sure I really follow here. `DAY` returns an `int` value, so are you just looking to have a column with the day number? If so, why not use a computed column instead?

Comment: Yes, I know that I can just convert this column to int type, but I'm curious if I can put just the day number in the date field?

Comment: A date consists of year, month and day. If you want to store the day alone, chose another data type.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I set just the day number inside a date field in SQL Server 2014?

Say you want to set a column to the first day of the month.  You would use `datefromparts()`:

```
UPDATE Calendar
    SET firstDayOfMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(year(date), month(date), 1);
```

Comment: I don't want the whole date (I don't want this: 'yyyy-mm-dd'), I just want: 'dd'

Comment: A DATE is always a date. You cannot set it to just "1" or January or 2021. Starting to sound like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In addition, a date is stored in an unreadable binary format. The format you see when you display a date is a product of the application you use.

Comment: @MAXIM7 . . . Then you don't want to store the value in a `date` column.